# Memory handling imagelist, out of memory

Tags: c#, listview, memory-management, imagelist

I've run into a real headache here.

I have a small program, which displays some images stored on disk. 8 images are displayed in a listview at a time, but when the images are large enough, the memory use (according to the task manager) reaches more than 1300mb! I suspect that there are some images or something which aren't deallocated, but I seem to be unable to pinpoint exactly where. I have tried both disposing all images in listview.largeimagelist.images, tried Clear()'ing the imagelist, but it doesn't make a difference at all.

Here is the current code:

```
    private void btnLoadNewImages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int k = lsvImgResult.Items.Count;
        for (k = lsvImgResult.Items.Count; k >= 1; k--)
        {
            Seen.Push((MyFile)lsvImgResult.Items[k - 1].Tag);
            imageList.Images.Clear();
        }


        int i = 0;

        lsvImgResult.Items.Clear();
        DisplayedImages.Clear();
        imageList.Images.Clear();

        imageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
        imageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

        int HowMany = 0;
        if (UnSeen.Count >= 8)
        {
            HowMany = 8;
        }
        else
        {
            HowMany = UnSeen.Count;
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= HowMany; i++)
        {
            MyFile CurFile = UnSeen.Pop();
            Image j = Image.FromFile(CurFile.Filename);
            DisplayedImages.Enqueue(CurFile);
            imageList.Images.Add(j);
        }

        lsvImgResult.LargeImageList = imageList;
        for (int j = 0; j < imageList.Images.Count; j++)
        {
            ListViewItem lstItem = new ListViewItem();
            lstItem.ImageIndex = j;
            lstItem.Tag = DisplayedImages.Dequeue();
            lstItem.ToolTipText = ((MyFile)lstItem.Tag).Filename;
            lsvImgResult.Items.Add(lstItem);
        }

        tabImagesLeft.Text = "Images left: " + UnSeen.Count;
    }
```

Comment: How many items are in this listview?  *Thousands* spells trouble, pretty hostile to the user as well.  You are not disposing images when you should.  Like after calling the Images.Add() method.

Comment: If i add j.Dispose(); directly after imageList.Images.Add(j);, i get a "parameter not valid" exception in the line : "lsvImgResult.LargeImageList = imageList;"

To answer your question, yes there could be thousands of images to work with : )

Comment: "Hostile" doesn't just describe the user experience.  Pay some attention to how programs do this.  Like Windows Explorer.  See how it can give access to *tens* of thousands of files on your C: drive without forcing you to claw through a list with tens of thousands of items.  It is smart about the icons as well, creating them only when necessary.

Comment: I know, and i acknowledge this. The problem is I don't know where to dispose the images correctly. Currently 8 images are in a list view at a time, and you can press load next 8 images, and load 8 previous images, so it is a sort of paging. But when should i dispose the images to deallocate the memory correctly?

Comment: Problem is solved. I decided that when the program only displays 8 images at a time, it is just as easy to use 8 pictureboxes...